# How to execute Jquery for element returned from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function in JS:

```
setRating();
```

And Jquery ready body with calling this function:

```
$(function(){
   setRating($('.ratings'));
});
```

Problem is that when I get HTML content from AJAX on page with elements `.ratings` then previous code does not work.

Seem I need to call `setRating()` in AJAX response after getting content?!

Comment: More relavant code please

Comment: _element returned from ajax_? How it will be in response? can you elaborate bit?

Comment: Please show us your ajax code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call this function after ajax is done
somethig like this:

```
 request = $.ajax({
                        ...
                    });
 request.done(function() {
                          ...
     setRating($('.ratings'));
 })
```

because when is function outside of request.done its called before content is created

Comment: I tried, it gives me `undefined function`, because `setRating` is inside document ready Jquery

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that this

```
$(function(){
   setRating($('.ratings'));
});
```

Is just shorthand for
`$(document).ready(function() { .. });`

That code is only ever executed once, when the document is marked as "ready".  You will indeed need to call `setRating()` when your new content arrives over AJAX

Comment: When I tried to call `setRating()` in success response AJAX, i get error: `setRating is not defined`. Because function is inside `$(function(){});`. How to resolve it?

Comment: Thats a scoping issue, you need to do `$(function() {var setRating = function() { ... }; $.ajax(url { .. });})`.   `setRating` just needs to be defined in the same scope or a parent scope of the ajax call